# Creating an Arraylist of Objects

Tags: java, android, object, arraylist

How do I fill an ArrayList with objects, with each object inside being different?

Comment: Use Generic class for these type of elements.
[Use the link for generic classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14391027/java-generics-in-android)

Comment: Refer Generic classes
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14391027/java-generics-in-android)

Answer (score 86, accepted):

```
ArrayList<Matrices> list = new ArrayList<Matrices>();
list.add( new Matrices(1,1,10) );
list.add( new Matrices(1,2,20) );
```

Answer (score 20):

#### How to Creating an Arraylist of Objects.

Create an array to store the objects:

```
ArrayList<MyObject> list = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
```

In a single step:

```
list.add(new MyObject (1, 2, 3)); //Create a new object and adding it to list.
```

or

```
MyObject myObject = new MyObject (1, 2, 3); //Create a new object.
list.add(myObject); // Adding it to the list.
```

Comment: ````MyObject myObject = new MyObject (1, 2, 3);````
This will call the constructor of MyObject class with 3 parameters. The question is about creating ArrayList with multiple different objects. I wonder why this has 20 upvotes.
Even this will create one object and add that to list: 

````list.add(new MyObject (1, 2, 3)); ````

Answer (score 4):

If you want to allow a user to add a bunch of new MyObjects to the list, you can do it with a for loop:
Let's say I'm creating an ArrayList of Rectangle objects, and each Rectangle has two parameters- length and width.

```
//here I will create my ArrayList:

ArrayList <Rectangle> rectangles= new ArrayList <>(3); 

int length;
int width;

for(int index =0; index <3;index++)
{JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Rectangle " + (index + 1));
 length = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter length");
 width = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter width");

 //Now I will create my Rectangle and add it to my rectangles ArrayList:

 rectangles.add(new Rectangle(length,width));

//This passes the length and width values to the rectangle constructor,
  which will create a new Rectangle and add it to the ArrayList.
```

}