# Dynamic Array of Objects Java

Tags: java, arrays, object

I'm doing a finance calculator in Java, and I need to be able to grab transaction info like Name, Amount, and Type. It needs to be dynamically sizable and able to hold the info.  Basically I need a mix between an ArrayList and an Array of Objects but I can't really find anything that exists.. By looking at this question [Creating an Arraylist of Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982550/creating-an-arraylist-of-objects), and the code below:

```
ArrayList<Matrices> list = new ArrayList<Matrices>();
list.add( new Matrices(1,1,10) );
list.add( new Matrices(1,2,20) );
```

it looks like I can create a new object each time that holds my data, so for my purposes it would look something like this

```
ArrayList<Payments> paymentList = new ArrayList<Payments>();
paymentList.add( new Payments(var1, var2, var3) );
```

Can I input variables into the ArrayList? Of course once I convert them all to strings (or could I keep them as String / Double / String since I'm technically adding an object to the ArrayList rather than a string value?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. If it is: can I add any kind of object into an ArrayList, the answer is yes. If it is: can a Payment object hold fields that are of type double in addition to other fields being of type String, the answer is of course also yes.

Comment: Ok, yeah both of those questions are relevant to my initial question. My question is more a 'this is my thought process, will it work' type of thing.

Another question now is, if I implement this, when I go to sort and search and all that, I'll have to basically run a loop that checks the paymentList ArrayList, and then within that check the Payments object correct?

Comment: No. You'll use Collections.sort() to sort the list. For searching, it depends on what you search, the size of the list and how often you search. A List is not necessarily the best datastructure to use. But without clear requirements, it's impossible to give a definitive answer. Read the [collections tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/).

Answer (score 0):

```
paymentList.add( new paymentList(var1, var2, var3) );
```

means you are about to add a new `Payments` instance into the arraylist (`paymentList`). regarding the type of var1,var2 and var3 (String or double). it depends on how did you define the constructor of your `Payments` class.

as long as you have an instance of Payments, you could add to that arrayList.