# java generics in Android

Tags: java, android, generics

I don't understand the following code:

```
public class EventAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Event> 
{
    public EventAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            List<Event> objects) 
    {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        this.resource = textViewResourceId;
    }
}
```

I am confused about the `<Event>` part in both cases. I understand it has something to do with Generics, but I don't understand it. I read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/, but still don't understand.

I do understand that `objects` is an `ArrayList` of objects of the type `Event`.

The part I don't understand is extending an ArrayAdapter with the Type `<Event>`. What does this signify?

Comment: What part don't you understand then?  I think you need to be a bit crisper on what's not understood for folks to help you.

Comment: Vague title, but then so is the question.

Comment: I updated my question to be more clear

Comment: You might be interested in finding the update to my answer -- I pointed out a more 'hypostatic' problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`extends ArrayAdapter<Event>`

The type restriction here will influence on the return types of methods in the class, and the argument types of methods.

Here is an example, if you have a class:

```
class SomeClass<T> {
    protected T value;

    public void setValue (T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public T getValue () {
        return value;
    }
}
```

And if you have another class:

```
class SubClass extends SomeClass {

    @Override
    public void setValue (Event value) {    // Fail! It is not overriding the super class' method.
        this.value = value;    // Warning! Unchecked types (maybe inconsistent).
    }
}
```

If you remove the `@Override` annotation, it will run. But the `extends SomeClass` is useless and might cause problem if you keep it there -- there will be two very similar methods: `setValue(Event)` and `super.setValue(T)`. Now the question is **will the subclass have access to the `super.setValue(T)` method?** I will explain it in the end, see "A missing type parameter bounding example".

So, you need to specify the type in declaration:

```
class SubClass extends SomeClass<Event> {

    @Override
    public void setValue (Event value) {    // Correct now!
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Also, if you declare an inconsistent type:

```
class SubClass extends SomeClass<String> {

    @Override
    public void setValue (Event value) {    // Fail! Not overriding.
        this.value = value;    // Fail! Inconsistent types.
    }
}
```

So the type restricts the behavior of class body.

---

---

### A missing type parameter bounding example:

---

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;

class Super<T> {
    public void method (T t) {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }

    public void method2 () {

    }
}

public class Test extends Super {
    /*public void method (Object t) {
        System.out.println("world");
    }*/

    /*public <T> void method (T t) {

    }*/

    public static void main (String args[]) {
        new Test().method("");
        for (Method m : Test.class.getMethods()) {
            System.out.println(m.toGenericString());
        }
    }
}
```

- If I comment `method()` in the subclass, it is compiled with a warning: `Test.java uses unchecked or unsafe opertations`. In the running result, it turned the generic type `T` into `Object`: `public void Test.method(java.lang.Object)`.
- If I only uncomment the first `method()` in the subclass, it is compiled with no warnings. In the running result, the subclass owns one `public void Test.method(java.lang.Object)`. But it doesn't allow `@Override` annotation.
- If I only uncomment the second `method()` in the subclass (which also has a generic type bounding), the compile fails with an error: `name clash`. It also doesn't allow `@Override` annotation. If you do so,  it throws a different error: `method does not override`.
- `method2()` is inherited by the subclass unanimously. But you also can't write the following code:

  in superclass: `public void method2 (Object obj)` and in subclass: `public <T> void method2 (T obj)`. They are also ambiguous and is not allowed by the compiler.

Answer (score 3):

Here's my simplistic way of looking at generics in this case. Given the definition:

```
public class EventAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Event>
```

I read it as: "An `EventAdapter` IS-A `ArrayAdapter` OF `Event` objects."

And I take `List<Event> objects` to mean a `List` of `Event` objects.

Collections are containers for objects, while Generics define what they can contain.

Answer (score 1):

This assigns a value for the generic parameter in ArrayAdapter in a way that takes away control from the user of the EventAdapter class.

Any method overriding here can then replace T with Event and Event can be used inplace of T without casts.

This is the general definition of generics.

That this is allowed in this case is defined in the [spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.4). While the exact behaviour is not defined in that section I think it is in line with all other generic behaviour as far as I can see.

While I see the construct here the first time, after some thinking it really isn't anything unusual.