# Java - Understanding Inheritance

Tags: java, object, inheritance

I'm new to Java and have been taking a course for a couple of weeks now and have been asked to complete a program with the following information:

> 1. Design a ship class that has the following data fields:
>
>    - A data field for the name of the ship (a string).
>    - A data field for the year that the ship was built (an int).
>    - A constructor and appropriate accessors and mutators.
>    - A toString method that displays the ship’s name and the year it was built.
> 2. Design a CruiseShip sub class that extends the Ship class. The CruiseShip class should have the following:
>
>    - An extra data field for the maximum number of passengers (an int).
>    - A constructor and appropriate accessors and mutators.
>    - A toString method that overrides the toString method in the base class. The CruiseShip class's toString method should also include the
>        max passenger limit.
> 3. Design a CargoShip class that extends the Ship class. The CargoShip class should have the following:
>
>    - An extra data field for the cargo capacity in tonnage (an int).
>    - A constructor and appropriate accessors and mutators.
>    - A toString method that overrides the toString method in the base class. The CargoShip class's toString method should also include the
>        cargo tonnage.
> 4. In the appropriate class include an equals method to test if two ships are equal - they should be considered equal if they have the
>      same name and were built in the same year.
> 5. Demonstrate the classes in a program (ShipTester) that has an array of Ship objects (at least 5 of them). Assign various Ship, CruiseShip,
>      and CargoShip objects to the array elements (you can hard-code the
>      objects and data) and print out the initial ship configurations. Show
>      that you can use both the accessor and mutator methods on a sampling
>      of the ships (again, you can hard-code the method arguments here if
>      you like).

I understand the basis of what the question is asking and I have done the following:

Ship.java

```
public class Ship {

    private String name;
    private int yearBuilt;

    public Ship(String name, int yearBuilt) {

        this.name = name;
        this.yearBuilt = yearBuilt;

    }

    public String returnName() {

        return this.name;

    }

    public int returnYear() {

        return this.yearBuilt;

    }

    public boolean equals(Ship other) {

        return false;

    }

    public String toString() {

        return "[Name: " + this.name + ". Year built: " + this.yearBuilt + "]";

    }
}
```

CruiseShip.java

```
public class CruiseShip extends Ship {

    private int maxPassengers;

    public CruiseShip() {

        super("USS Enterprise", 2245);

        this.maxPassengers = 2400;

    }

    public CruiseShip(String name, int yearBuilt, int maxPassengers) {

        super(name, yearBuilt);
        this.maxPassengers = maxPassengers;

    }

    public String toString() {

        return "Cruise Ship" + super.toString() + ", Passengers: " + this.maxPassengers + "]";

    }

}
```

CargoShip.java

```
public class CargoShip extends Ship {

    private int cargoCapacity;

    public CargoShip() {

        super("Black Pearl", 1699);

        this.cargoCapacity = 50000;

    }

    public CargoShip(String name, int yearBuilt, int cargoCapacity) {

        super(name, yearBuilt);
        this.cargoCapacity = cargoCapacity;

    }

    public String toString() {

        return "Cargo Ship" + super.toString() + ", Tonnage: " + this.cargoCapacity + "]";

    }

}
```

and in my tester file - ShipTester.java

```
public class ShipTester {
    public static void main(String []args) {

        //I don't know what to put over here...

    }
}
```

I don't know what to put in the main method... I do know I have to create an array of ships but i don't know how to do that with the cargo ship, cruise ship and so on...

Output that i'm supposed to have:

Displaying Ships:
Ship[ Name: Queen Annes Revenge Year built: 1701]

Cruise Ship[ Ship[ Name: USS Enterprise Year built: 2245], Passengers: 2400 ]

Cargo Ship[ Ship[ Name: Black Pearl Year built: 1699], Tonnage: 50000 ]

Cruise Ship[ Ship[ Name: USS Voyager Year built: 2371], Passengers: 2800 ]

Cargo Ship[ Ship[ Name: The Victory Year built: 1790], Tonnage: 33100 ]

Comment: Hint, you just said the answer: *...I have to create an array of ships...*

Comment: `Ship[] ships = new Ship[5];` and then assign `ships[0] = ....`. You can do this, I'm sure, just give it a go and see what happens.

Comment: Also, your `equals` method is incorrect in your `Ship` class. It needs to test `yearBuilt` and `name` per your requirements.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, yeah I left that for later. thanks for reminding me

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels yeah but what I don't understand is: `ships[0] = //what?` like how do i give the name and year

Comment: You use a constructor from one of your ***concrete*** Ship-derived classes. Or call Ship's constructor if you want a plain vanilla Ship object. Again, give it a try. ;)

Comment: I see the word `new` in your future...

Comment: Are all cruise ships named the "USS Enterprise"? I doubt it.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, i thought the constructor would set the name for the ship from what it gets from the tester class

Comment: @user3148597 Req1 bullet point `c` (the third one).

Comment: By the way, you should always override `hashCode` when overriding `equals`, because otherwise containers like `HashMap` will malfunction. It's usually best to leave `equals` alone (using the default `==` implementation) until you write an actual implementation of it.

Comment: @user3148597 It does, but you should leave it to the caller of that constructor, and not hard-code a name for it at the class level. What happens if you want to create another cruise ship named "USS Ambassador"?

Comment: @Santa She's providing a default... it's not the worst idea ever - but you should use `this()` instead of `super()`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Yeah, but that not a very good default, IMO. `"Unnamed"` or something like that would be less misleading.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, so for the appropriate accessors and mutators, is the default constructor not enough? i have to create methods such as `setName`, `setYearBuilt` and so on? and for the mutator methods, should i have it as `changeName(String nameToChangeTo);`?

Comment: @user3148597 Sorry you don't have to do anything. This is 100% free advice. The mutators are normally named with `set` and the accessors are named with `get`. I strongly suspect your instructor wants to see what is normally referred to as a "[JavaBean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBean)".

Comment: @ElliottFrisch so for only the ship class i need the setName and setYear, getName and getYear, right?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch @santa thank you! can I get a hint on how to do the equals method? I'm thinking something along the lines of `public boolean equals(ship[0], ship[1])`

Comment: @Santa can i get a hint on the equals method?

Comment: @user3148597 Use the `@Override` annotation. Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8180430/how-to-override-equals-method-in-java) question.

Answer (score 2):

Extending onto what Hovercraft said but you may want to use an ArrayList for arrays of objects.

[Creating an Arraylist of Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982550/creating-an-arraylist-of-objects)

Example

```
ArrayList<Ship> myArray = new ArrayList();
myArray.add(new CargoShip("TheKing",1990,10000));
myArray.add(new CruiseShip("Princess",2000,5000));
```

etc.

[edit] forgot you needed to print it too

You use a simple for loop to print, example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.size(); i++) {
  System.out.println(myArray.get(i).toString());
}
```

note - this is not the exact answer I dont want jump over your learning process. But this should at least give you an idea of a path you could take...

Comment: 1) His instructions mention creating an array, not a collection such as an ArrayList. 2) The `toString()` call is not needed inside of a `println(...)` statement since it is called by default. The latter is a minor quibble, but the first statement of mine is more major.

Answer (score 0):

`Ship` is the "base" parent class which puts all the other classes into a common family.  This means that `CruiseShip` and `CargoShip` can actually masquerade as `Ship`.  This is the corner stone of [Polymorphism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html) and one of the features that makes Object Oriented Program so powerful.

Based on your example code, you would simply need to create an array of type `Ship`, for example...

```
Ship[] ships = new Ship[5];
```

You would then simply need to fill this arrays with an assortment of ships...

```
ships[0] = new CargoShip("Lolli Pop", 1965, 1990);
ships[1] = new CruiseShip("Love Boat", 1980, 8);
```

What this means is, that each element "acts" as a `Ship`, since `CargoShip` and `CruiseShip` inherited from `Ship`, this gives them the ability to do so, because they are "ships"

Because the display information for `Ship` is defined by it's `toString` method you can simply use `System.out.println(instanceOfShip)` to print it.  For example...

```
for (Ship ship : ships) {
    System.out.println(ship);
}
```

Take a closer look at [Inheritance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) and [Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) for more details

It might seem confusing and daunting, but once you understand the basics of inheritance, it will become very obvious and very powerful

Comment: thank you! can I get a hint on how to do the equals method? I'm thinking something along the lines of `public boolean equals(ship[0], ship[1])`

Comment: *"they should be considered equal if they have the same name and were built in the same year"* would suggest that `returnName` and `returnYear` need to be the same for both ships.  `equals` is usually done by passing one instance to another ie `ship[0].equals(ship[1])`, based on the example in the answer