# Accessing elments from ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I've learnt how to [Create an Arraylist of Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982550/creating-an-arraylist-of-objects) , such arrays are dynamic in nature. e.g. to create an array of objects(instances of class Matrices ) having 3 fields, the code is like given below :

```
ArrayList<Matrices> list = new ArrayList<Matrices>();
list.add( new Matrices(1,1,10) );
list.add( new Matrices(1,2,20) );
```

Moreover, the `Matrices` class goes like this:

```
public class Matrices{
int x;
int y;
int z;

Matrices(int x,int y, int z){
this.x = x;
this.y = y;
this.z = z;
}
}
```

Now, how can I *access each fields* of any element from this array name `list` ? In particular, how to access the `20` field from 2nd element of this array whose value is (1,2,20) ?

Comment: Please check the java API for these fundamental questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just use the `get` method:

```
// 2nd element; Java uses 0-based indexing almost everywhere
Matrices element = list.get(1);
```

What you do with the `Matrices` reference afterwards is up to you - you've shown the constructor call, but we don't know whether those values are then exposed as properties or anything else.

In general, when you're using a class you should look at its documentation - in this case the [documentation for `ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). Look down the list of methods, trying to find something that matches what you're trying to do.

You should also read the [tutorial on collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/) for more information about the collections library in Java.

Comment: exactly this documentation was all I needed .I'll bookmark it for future reference . thanx

Comment: Can you also help me in iterating through each elements of ArrayList using for-each construct ?

Comment: @KunalKrishna: No, there are *lots* of examples out there. I'd expect pretty much any tutorial on the enhanced for loop to use it as an example. Stack Overflow is great for very specific questions, but it's not a good way of learning a language from scratch. You'd be better off with a good book to work through.

Answer (score 1):

`Matrices element = list.get(1);` will do the job. ArrayList is a zero index collection. So [`list.get(1)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get%28int%29) will give the 2nd element.

You should check relevant apis, here [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Answer (score 0):

I see this as a search algorithm question.

You iterate through the `list`, and check if the current iteration's element contains the desired values.

Comment: I don't think that's what the OP wants - he's specifically trying to access the 2nd element, so just calling `list.get(1)` does that.

Comment: @JonSkeet `In particular, how to access the 20 field from 2nd element of this array whose value is (1,2,20)` this feels rather vague to me.

Comment: Yes, but that the "how to access the 20 field" isn't addressed by your answer either...

Answer (score 0):

```
Matrices m = list.get(1)
```

read java docs please

Answer (score 0):

You can get Matrices object from list as:

```
 Matrices m = list.get(0);// fist element in list
 m.anyPublicMethod();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Matrice m = list.get(1);
int twenty = m.getThirdElement(); // or whatever method you named to get the 3rd element (ie 20);

// in one go :
twenty = list.get(1).getThirdElement();
```