# How can you create multiple objects for the same class without knowing the amount of objects needed?

Tags: java, object

I want to be able to give the program a number between 2 and 10 and it create that many objects from the same class in Java.

I'm not sure the best way to do this. The only way I can think of is that I make 10 if/else if statements and make the objects that way.

```
if (num == 2){
  Class object1 = new Class(1)
  Class object2 = new Class(2)

}
else if (num == 3){
  Class object1 = new Class(1)
  Class object2 = new Class(2)
  Class object3 = new Class(3)
}

.
.
.

else if (num == 10){
  Class object1 = new Class(1)
  Class object2 = new Class(2)
  Class object3 = new Class(3)
  Class object4 = new Class(4)
  Class object5 = new Class(5)
  Class object6 = new Class(6)
  Class object7 = new Class(7)
  Class object8 = new Class(8)
  Class object9 = new Class(9)
  Class object10 = new Class(10)
}
```

Is there a better way to do this? I'm still learning to code so I'm not the best at it. Someone said something about an array of objects but I don't know what that is or if it relates to this problem. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating an Arraylist of Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982550/creating-an-arraylist-of-objects)

Comment: Aside: don't call your class `Class`.

Answer (score 4):

Given the input you can create the objects inside a for loop and add it one-by-one in an `ArrayList`.

```
List<Class> list = new ArrayList<>();

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){ // n is the number of objects to be created.
   list.add(new Class(i+1));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use an array:

```
Class[] objects;
```

then

```
objects = new Class[num];
for (int i = 1; i <= num; ++i) {
    objects[i-1] = new Class(i);
}
```

Note that array indexing starts at 0.

It's worth through through the [arrays tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) on the Oracle Java website (or, of course, the arrays section of any good beginner's Java book or tutorial).