# Converting String into Array

Tags: java, string, arraylist

How do I convert the text

> "[user1,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5]"

into an ArrayList? Please note that each element should be a string.

Such to say:

```
String str = "[user1,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5]"
ArrayList<> aryList = ...
```

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating an Arraylist of Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982550/creating-an-arraylist-of-objects)

Comment: @WJS Is there a way to do it without Objects? It's for a project and we have to write accompanying pseudocode (for some reason ik) and the guide doesn't specify how to convert Objects into pseudocode

Comment: Use String.split()` on the commas to get an array of tokens Then you can fill an array list of string by iterating over the tokens.  Use `List<String> list = new Arra`yList<>() ` to create the list.  You will need to clean up your tokens somewhat (e.g. braces, etc).

Comment: `List<String> aryList = Arrays.asList(str.substring(1, str.length() -1).split(",\\s*"));`

Comment: If I use split(), The first value, for example, would be "[user1" and I don't want that bracket

Comment: Use String.substring(1, string.length() -1).  You may also want to trim the white space off each token.

Comment: Thanks @WJS and YCF_L. Your suggestions work :)

Answer (score 0):

this answer hold good only in case you are have a string starting with [ and ending with ]
i took an example from your question. you have many ways to delimit the string and split it to list of string.
@Note : i have just wrote a test method so that you can test the code

```
@Test
public void test(){
    String value = "[user1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]";
    List<String> valueList = Arrays.asList(value.substring(value.indexOf('[')+1, value.lastIndexOf(']')).split(","));
    System.out.println("Value list is "+valueList);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In pure Java, you could just remove the braces and then split the string on the comma and two spaces that you have delimiting each entry:

```
String text = "[user1,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5]";

// This will create a List of 6 strings:
List<String> splitList = Arrays.asList(text.replaceAll("[", "").replaceAll("]", "").split(",  "));
```

If the entries in your array are quoted, then this syntax is just the syntax for arrays in JSON. You could use a Jackson `ObjectMapper` to read the string to a list:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String text = "[\"user1\",  \"1\",  \"2\",  \"3\",  \"4\",  \"5\"]";
List<String> splitStrings = objectMapper.readValue(text, new TypeReference<List<String>>(){});
```